# (c++) Function calculating average returns (first score / total number of scores)?

Tags: c++

So the program gathers a number of scores specified, then displays them in ascending order, then *is supposed to* show the average score. But right now, it only takes the first score displayed, and is divided by the number of scores. How can I make it display correctly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void sortArray(int*, int);
double getAverage(int*, int);


int main()
{
int *scores;
int num_Tests;

cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter?" << endl;
cin  >> num_Tests;

scores = new int[num_Tests];

cout << "\nEnter score number (do not use negative numbers):\n";
    for (int count = 0; count < num_Tests; count++)
    {
    cout << count + 1 << ". ";
    cin >> scores[count];
    }

sortArray(scores, num_Tests);

cout << "\n\n";
cout << "\n\n________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
cout << "Test Score List (in ascending order)" << endl;
cout << "________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

    for (int count = 0; count < num_Tests; count++)
    {
    cout << count + 1 << ". ";
    cout << scores[count] << endl;
    }

cout << "\nAverage test score: " << getAverage(scores, num_Tests) << endl;

return 0;
}

double getAverage(int *scores, int size)
{
double ttlScore = 0.0;
double avgScore = 0.0;

ttlScore += *scores;
avgScore = ttlScore / size;

return avgScore;
}

void sortArray(int *scores, int size)
{
int temp;
bool swap;

    do
    { swap = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if (scores[count] < scores[count + 1])
            {
            temp = scores[count];
            scores[count] = scores[count + 1];
            scores[count + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

Comment: You know that the average would be the sum of all the scores divided by the number. So begin by calculating the sum.

Comment: you need to loop through your scores array to add them, you cannot just do `ttlScore += *scores`, it needs to be `ttlScore += scores[index]`

Comment: another point I might raise is that this code could be a bit neater if you used more functions in your main (to display output for example). Its a matter of personal preference but I like my main functions neat :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your scores array to add them, you cannot just do `ttlScore += *scores`, it needs to be `ttlScore += scores[index]`

Example:

```
double getAverage(int *scores, int size)
{
    double ttlScore = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ttlScore += scores[i];
    }

    return ttlScore / size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getAverage logic is not correct. You are adding just first number. Add is as below:

```
   double getAverage(int *scores, int size)
   {
     double ttlScore = 0.0;
     double avgScore = 0.0;

     for(int i=0;i<size;i++) 
     { 
      ttlScore += *(scores+i);
     }
      avgScore = ttlScore / size;
      return avgScore;
   }
```

Comment: why do you declare `i` outside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

*scores references the start of the array. You need to sum over all of the values of the array pointed to:

```
for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
{
ttlScore += scores[i];
}
avgScore = ttlScore / size;

return avgScore;
```

Comment: it would be better to do `return ttlScore / size` as in my code

Comment: What Matthew said - fewer operations. Recently a cause of major slowdown in some code I wrote. Clearly I haven't learnt!

Comment: and also uses less memory, not important for code this small but its good to get into good habits early

Answer (score 0):

I think these will help you,

double getAverage(int *scores, int size){

```
 int    i, sum = 0;       
 double avg;          

for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
   sum += scores[i];
   }

 avg = (double)sum / size;

 return avg;
```

}

Try and let me know if any  problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to programming but here is what I have.

```
//average function

double average(int* pnData)

{

     double result;

     int sum = 0;     //declare and initialize our variables
     int count = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < pnData[i]; i++)
     {
          sum += pnData[i];  //sum = sum + elements of our array
          count++;           //increment count
     }//end of for loop

     result = sum/(double)count;
     return result;
}//end of function average
```

This way you do not have to know the length or count of the array.